# I am trying to use a slider component in my angular project i have ran the ng add @angular/material still the following error

Tags: angular-material

**ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/material/slider" has missing dependencies:**
     - @angular/cdk/a11y
     - @angular/cdk/bidi
     - @angular/cdk/coercion
     - @angular/cdk/keycodes
     - @angular/cdk/platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing your node_modules/ directory and running npm install. maybe @angular/cdk is not installed properly